# Any good design pattern to use for extracting HTML from business logic in PHP?

Tags: php, design-patterns, refactoring

I have an old PHP4 web app in which most of the pages looks like this(some pages has a left menu, some doesn't have a footer):

```
<?php
  echo "<html>";
  echo "<head><title>TITLE GOES HERE</title></head";
  echo "<body>";
  echo "<h2>THIS IS A TITLE</h2>";
  // Here i fetch data from DB
  echo "<table>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "</tr>";
  foreach($rowsFromDB as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    // here i echo some <td> containing $row data
    echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
  echo "</body>";
  echo "</html>";
?>
```

This is a simple example, the real ones contains a lot of spaghetti code (i'm italian, i like spaghetti but not in my code) and i'm trying to refactor/redesign it in some way. Rewrite the entire app from scratch (maybe with an MVC framework) is not an option because the app contains a lot of business logic i would like to keep.
My idea (for now) is to wrap the `echo`s inside a renderer class, something like this:

```
<?php
  class PageRenderer {
    public static function renderHeader() {
      echo "<html>";
      echo "<head><title>TITLE GOES HERE</title></head";
      echo "<body>";
      echo "<h2>THIS IS A TITLE</h2>";
    }

    public static function renderContent($rowsFromDB) {
      echo "<table>";
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "</tr>";
      foreach($rowsFromDB as $row) {
        echo "<tr>";
        // here i echo some <td> containing $row data
        echo "</tr>";
      }
      echo "</table>";
    }

    public static function renderFooter() {
      echo "</body>";
      echo "</html>";
    }
  }

  $renderer=new PageRenderer();
  $renderer->renderHeader();
  // Fetch data from DB
  $renderer->renderResults($rowsFromDB);
  $renderer->renderFooter();
?>
```

The problem with the above solution is that is difficult to extend and maintain. Do you know any design pattern or any technique i could use for a better refactoring/redesign?
Thanks in advice and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a method, maybe call it `renderColumn($tdParams = array())` which only has simple job of returning a single td element (as a string):

- Initialize an empty string, `$td_cell`
- Append to `$td_cell` an opening `<td>` tag, maybe accept an array of attributes and values for said `td` tag as paramater `$tdParams` which has been set a default value of an empty array.
- Append to `$td_cell` a closing `</td>` tag.
- `return $td_cell`

For rendering out your DB Rows, you may (at later point in time) have a query that has more, or less data points - thus will result in needing more or less `td` cells.

For your `renderHeader` method, I would add at least 2 parameters: `title` and maybe for the `<h2>` as you specified, as I can see that changing frequently.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but as I mentioned in the question, I don't like the solution I proposed and I'm looking for something better

Comment: @WileTheCoyot Ok, I see now. Well. I think I understand now what you would like to do. Perhaps another approach is to see if there's an MVC Framework in PHP that you like.  There are many to choose from that will probably fit your requirement. You would simply need to manage the views and layouts after customizing a data model and issue command from controller.  Might be more fun that trying to write something that already does what you need ?

Comment: yeah, i think in the end i should go with an MVC framework. Let's hope someone know some good pattern to use (reimplement all the thing will be a huge work)

Comment: @WileTheCoyot since you know your data structure, the effort of configuring & coding to adapt (in theory) should be less than trying to re-invent something you're currently not happy with.  I've only used a few frameworks of PHP to date so I cannot make an informed recommendation. What I can say is that Laravel seems very popular and I've used Zend 1.12, even though Zend is far into V2 these days. Good luck.